# Setting a indeterminate progress bar on an AndroidX toolbar

Tags: android, toolbar, android-progressbar

I am used to just use

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

to show my "loading" progress bar. When trying this now, nothing happens. I tried to implement it separately like this:

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

and using

```
    ProgressBar progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

to show it. But it is still not showing.

How can I (simply) show a indeterminate progress bar with AndroidX?

Comment: I'm struggling with this today too. Any resolution Bart?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have added a progress bar inside a toolbar, you need to initialize toolbar first and then using toolbarObject , initiated progressBar.

Answer (score 0):

The layout_width property of the toolbar is 0dp change it to match_parent.

Comment: I tried, but adding the progressbar caused the toolbar to grow in height